# Using visual studio, is there any way to keep properties settings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have to set "C++ Language standard" to "C++ 20" and "multi-processor compilation" to yes every time I open a new project.

Is there any way to keep the setting? Thanks.

Comment: Any updates? Do the methods  below work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create prop file. For your reference:[Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this by customizing project templates. See [Customize project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-project-and-item-templates?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022) for details.

E.g. if you edit `project.vcxproj` file in `%DevEnvInstallDir%\ProjectTemplates\VC\WindowsDesktop\` directory and add `ItemDefinitionGroup` section with `LanguageStandard` setting as shown below, then new C++ projects will have this section in `*.vcxproj` files. Probably you'd better not directly change the preinstalled templates, but to make copies of the required one(s) and customize them instead. Also there might be a more accurate place to put this setting, please do some research.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
$projectconfigurations$
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <Keyword>$keyword$</Keyword>
    <ProjectGuid>{$guid1$}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>$rootnamespace$</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>$windowstargetplatformversion$</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
$labeledpropertygroups$
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared" >
  </ImportGroup>
$propertysheets$
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
$propertygroups$
$itemdefinitiongroups$
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp20</LanguageStandard>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup></ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```